# Git clone issue into specific folder

Tags: centos7, user-permissions

I have an issue with cloning private repository into my instance(`ec2: CentOS 7`).
I've generated the key and added it to github.

The problem is when I'm trying to clone it into `/home/app` directory (`Permission denied (publickey)...`), but when I run the same command in `/home/ec2-user/app` it works fine.

Looks like a permissions issue.
My command:

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:.../my_website.git
```

Would be appreciate for any advise

I solved it by running:
`sudo chmod 777 app`

But I don't think it's a perfect solution

Comment: Normal users are usually not allowed to create new home-directories, they are restricted to their own home-directory, in this case `/home/ec2-user/`. How did you even create the `app` directory in `/home/` without `sudo`?

Comment: Giving access to everyone is a bad idea. Did you try changing the owner to `ec2-user`?

Comment: Finally I just moved the project folder under `/home/ec2-user` folder. 
Other folders that I used to create outside I just granted the ec2-user permissions
Thanks